# Calculate tax based on product category

Tags: php

Below you can see a class and a function. The class is just an dummy entity. The function has a switch statement. That switch statement calculates the tax by to a predefined hardcoded string, and I don't like that. What's next, this switch statement violates the Open/Closed principle.

The class entity:

```
class Product {
    private int $id;
    private string $name;
    private int $price;
    private string $category;
    
    public function __construct(int $id, string $name, int $price, string $category) {
        $this->id = $id;
        $this->name = $name;
        $this->price = $price;
        $this->category = $category;
    }
    public function getId(): int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }
    public function getName(): string
    {
        return $this->name;
    }
    public function getPrice(): int
    {
        return $this->price;
    }
    public function getCategory(): string
    {
        return $this->category;
    }
}
```

The client code:

```
//$product = new Product(200, 'Bread', 200, 'Food'); // A different product category
$product = new Product(100, 'Chair', 5000, 'Furniture');

$taxForChair = calculateTax($product);
var_dump($taxForChair); // float 1050
exit;

function calculateTax(Product $product): float {
    // The switch statement below decreases adaptablity.
    // The function also violates the Open/Closed principle.
    // At this point, it has 2 cases. 
    // When the Business Rule change by create a new product category, then this function needs to change too.
    switch($product->getCategory()) {
        case 'Furniture':
            $tax = $product->getPrice() / 100 * 21; 
            break;
        case 'Food':
            $tax = $product->getPrice() / 100 * 9; 
            break;
        default:
            $tax = 0;
            break;
    }
    
    return (float)$tax;
}
```

Would you be so kind and write a better `calculateTax` function?

Comment: These comments looks like teacher's remarks

Comment: @YourCommonSense they were my own, so that means you think I'm a teacher. I take that as a compliment :-)

Comment: Welcome to the Code Review Community. We make suggestions on how the code can be improved, we don't re-write the code. Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I think you are better off creating an interface `Product` and concrete classes that implement those interfaces or abstract class.  In each concrete class you define getPrice to be specific to that product and you get rid of the switch statement and simply call getPrice().

Answer (score 1):

The fundamental problem here is that category and tax rate have no particular reason to be associated with one another.  In general, category would be used in a system like this to determine what products are marketed in the same list.  But tax rate is based on a taxable class of products.  For example, you might have categories for pots and pans, but your tax rate might vary based on the composition.  So iron pots and iron pans would get the same tax rate while aluminum pots and pans could get a different tax rate.

You could either make tax rate a characteristic of the product, e.g.

```
public function calculateTax(): float {
    return $this->getPrice() / 100 * $this->getTaxRate();
}
```

Or you could make the tax class a property of the product and tax rate a property of the tax class.

```
public static function calculateTax(Product $product): float {
    return $product->getPrice() / 100 * $product->getTaxClass()->getTaxRate();
}
```

or

```
public calculateTax(): float {
    return $this->getPrice() / 100 * $this->getTaxClass()->getTaxRate();
}
```

Then you could change the tax rates for many products at once by changing the rate on a single tax class.  Which is consistent with how governments usually charge them.

I would tend to prefer to make tax calculation a method on the product and make the rate a property of the tax class.

And again, this allows you to assign products to categories without worrying about how that will affect their taxation.

Note that beyond all this, you probably want to store the configuration in some kind of data store (e.g. a database).  Because changing a product price or tax class should not require editing code.  There are any number of open source PHP shopping carts that already have these capabilities and more.

The real violation of the Open/Closed principle here is that if the tax rate changes, you have to modify code.  Because you are hard coding the tax rate in your files.  Whether you use a switch or a class extension is beside the point.  You are hard coding your business ***data*** in your files.  You should have a separate store from which you can get the data.  The only files that should have hard coded data are test files.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by myself by introducing abstract classes, see below:

```
class Product {
    private int $id;
    private string $name;
    private int $price;
    private Category $category;
    
    public function __construct(int $id, string $name, int $price, Category $category) {
        $this->id = $id;
        $this->name = $name;
        $this->price = $price;
        $this->category = $category;
    }
    public function getId(): int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }
    public function getName(): string
    {
        return $this->name;
    }
    public function getPrice(): int
    {
        return $this->price;
    }
    public function getCategory(): Category
    {
        return $this->category;
    }
}
```

here it goes

```
abstract class Category { 
    abstract public function calculateTax(int $price): float;
}
class CategoryFurniture extends Category {
    public function calculateTax(int $price): float {
        return (float)($price / 100 * 21);
    }
}
class CategoryFood extends Category {
    public function calculateTax(int $price): float {
        return (float)($price / 100 * 9);
    }
}

//$product = new Product(200, 'Bread', 200, new CategoryFood); 
$product = new Product(100, 'Chair', 5000, new CategoryFurniture);

$taxForChair = calculateTax($product);
var_dump($taxForChair); // float 1050
exit;

function calculateTax(Product $product): float {
    
    $price = $product->getPrice();
    
    $category = $product->getCategory();
    return $category->calculateTax($price);
}
```

Comment: As long as the tax is calculated using the same formula,I would rather store the actual values in the *database*. This way you won't have to edit any code at all.